# GMaps API v3 - jQuery - Problems with array

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps-api-3

I am building an google map on my web page. This map has some markers. These markers are created with information of a json file. This all works fine. But when I want to use a list of all markers, this list.length is always 0 in an other function. Only in the function where i put the markers into the list, the list isn't empty.

I made a fidler of my code, so it's more viewable for you guys.

The problem is with the array "positions" and the function buttons.
The alert in the buttons function, shows 0. And I have no idea why..

Thanks in advance!

Here my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cJxcV/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is simple. You are calling `Ajax` **asyncronously**. When you are trying to alert `positions.length` value, your `Ajax` is not being delivered yet,and your `position` array is not populated with values and is empty(`.length=0`).  Put `buttons()` call inside of the callback:

```
loadMarkers();
//buttons();
//     |    //.............
//     |    //.............
//     |    //.............
            polyline.setMap(map);
//     ---> 
            buttons();
      });
```